# Target .NET Framework beta v4.0.2 instead of the release v4.0.3

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

For some unusual reasons, I need my vb.net application to be compiled with `v4.0.2` or `v4.0.1` runtime libraries. With VS 2010 Ultimate, my app compiled with the default runtime (v4.0.30319).

When I set the target framework to 4.0.2, I get a message:

> you must install v4.0.3xxx .NET Framework

I know it seems a bit weird but I won't install this exact version.

How can I target a specific framework version for my application?

Comment: You should probably address whatever the "unusual reasons" are rather than tying your application to a very specific patch level of the framework.

Comment: Solve the real problem, not find the awkward workarounds. Don't rely on behaviour/defects in one framework minor point releases.

Comment: The real problem:
I'm trying to virtualize dotnet framework application using spoon studio. Spoon only support v4.0, 4.1 and 4.2 :)

Comment: I contacted Spoon Studio support team and then sent me some special framework, and instead choosing the default provided framework from the GUI, I added this component manually. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you mean is that you want to install a beta version of the framework.  If that's the case, then no.  You can't.  At least not legally.  Your beta license expires the moment the release version is available, and you are given a small gracetime to upgrade.

There is no release version with a 4.0.1 or 4.0.2 version number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry if i wasn't that clear in my question. The solution came from Spoon support (see my last comment on the original question).